# Accessing XML attributes data

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have two lines of XML data that are attributes but also contain data inside then and they are repeating fields. They are being stored in a SimpleXML variable.

```
<inputField Type="Name">John Doe</inputField>
<inputField Type="DateOfHire">Tomorrow</inputField>
```

(Clearly this isnt real data but the syntax is actually in my data and I'm just using string data in them)

Everything that I've seen says to access the data like this, ,which I have tried and it worked perfectly. But my data is dynamic so the data isn't always going to be in the same place, so it doesn't fit my needs.

```
$xmlFile->inputField[0];
$xmlFile->inputField[1];
```

This works fine until one of the lines is missing, and I can have anywhere from 0 to 5  lines. So what I was wondering was is there any way that I can access the data by attribute name? So potentially like this.

```
$xmlFile->inputField['Name'];
```

or

```
$xmlFile->inputField->Name;
```

I use these as examples strictly to illustrate what I'm trying to do, I am aware that neither of the above lines of code are syntactically correct.

Just a note this information is being generated externally so I cannot change the format.

If anyone needs clarification feel free to let me know and would be happy to elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
echo $xmlFile->inputField->attributest()->Name;
```

And what you're using? DOMDocument or simplexml?

Comment: I'm wrote example for simplexml.

Comment: Thank you that worked like a charm, and actually I had tried it before, but my live data has a space in it, `"firstword secondword"`, and that space was throwing things off. Do you know if there's a way to access that with spaces in the quotes. i.e `"First Name"` instead of just `"Name"`

Comment: @choppyfireballs If I understood you correctly, try like this
`echo $xmlFile->inputField->attributest()->{'First Name'};`

Answer (score 0):

You don't say, but I assume you're using `SimpleXMLElement`?

If you want to access every item, just iterate:

```
foreach ($xmlFile->inputField as $inputField) { ... }
```

If you want to access an attribute use array notation:

```
$inputField['Type']
```

If you want to access only one specific element, use xpath:

```
$xmlFile->xpath('inputField[@Type="Name"]');
```

Perhaps you should read through the [basic examples of usage in the SimpleXMLElement documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)?

Comment: I was looking to access one specific element and I already knew how to access the data using foreach and using array annotation, which I learned how to do using php's onling documentation, before I posted the question and it did not contain what I needed. So I tried out using xpath like you suggested, and all xpath is returning to me is. `array`

Comment: `xpath` returns an array of matching elements. Look in the first element of the array.

Comment: This also worked as well too bad I can't pick two answers. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can a grab a data:

```
$xmlFile = simplexml_load_file($file);

foreach($xmlFile->inputField as $res) {

    echo $res["Name"];

}
```